# Launching COM (.NET) Object with Elevated Rights throws FileNotFoundException

Tags: .net, security, com, uac, elevated-privileges

I am trying to launch a .NET object through the CoGetObject method as outlined in the [COM Elevation Moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687.aspx) article on MSDN.  I started working with the Vista Bridge code and then stumbled across an [older sample that shows some of the bits wired up](http://chrison.net/UACElevationInManagedCodeGuidanceForImplementingCOMElevation.aspx).  At this point I am trying to figure out why I am getting a FileNotFoundException thrown when the call goes through to this method:

```
var result = UnsafeNativeMethods.CoGetObject(monikerName, ref bindingOptions, interfaceId);
```

The exception only throws after the consent prompt is displayed which is strange.  I am working on a Windows 7 x64 machine if that helps and have [posted the full source of my spike](https://bitbucket.org/ColinBowern/elevationsample/src).

What am I missing here that might cause a FileNotFoundException to be thrown?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your situation but it might be useful to identify where it's trying to find the file/what it's expecting. I'd suggest you download ProcMon (Process Monitor) from the Sysinternals website - you should be able to filter the events to show only file not founds for your process - Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Did you run RegAsm.exe with the /tlb switch to export and register a typelib for the COM server? Not having a registered typelib may result in a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Tried that, as well as watching with Process Monitor; couldn't find any file I/O that had gone astray.

Comment: Is the assembly (and all its dependencies) in the GAC?

Answer (score 0):

This is not directly an answer, but you can probably use the [RunElevatedNet](https://github.com/forderud/RunInSandbox/tree/master/RunElevatedNet) C# sample project to try launching your COM server in either a elevated project or not. Investigating if the same FileNotFoundException error also occur in non-elevated mode might help debug your issue.